# Making an array of strings bigger or smaller in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array of strings `char *array[5];` which has 5 elements inside, but I need to use it again. How can I put something else in it? How can I make it bigger or smaller(so that it won't take up much memory).
Example:

```
char *array[4];
array[0]= "A";
array[1]= "BB";
array[2]= "CCC";
array[3]= NULL; //I need the last one to be null
```

But now I need it again to store maybe only `{"A", NULL}` or `{"A", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD", NULL}`

I have another function that takes care of what needs to be stored in the array, it just splits the input of the user by words and stores them in the array. The input of the user will be known before needing the array, so I will know how many words will be and how bigger the array should be. The user will be asked for input multiple times, that's why I need to rewrite the array.
I have a doubt that I will need to use malloc/realloc, but if anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated, every response is welcomed!

Comment: You have declared an array of 4 elements. You cannot make it bigger or smaller. You may look into the concept of dynamic memory allocation using the functions `malloc`, `free` and `realloc`.

Comment: You can use VLA.  E.g `char *words[NumberOfWords+1];`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: are they standard-compliant?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo VLA can be used since C99.

Comment: Thank you guys! My problem is that by using malloc my code won't compile, maybe I am doing it wrong. How can we allocate memory for 5 elements so that we would end up with the same result as char *array[5];

Comment: `char **array = malloc(sizeof(*array)*5 /* 5 : number of words+1 */);`... `free(array);`

Answer (score 1):

If you need a resizable array, you have two options:

1. Use a *large enough* array and keep track of its size.

   ```
   const size_t MAX_SIZE = 255;

   void resize(char** array, size_t* curr_size, size_t new_size)
   {
       assert(new_size <= MAX_SIZE);
       *curr_size = new_size;
       array[new_size - 1] = NULL;
   }

   // ...

   int main()
   {
       char* array[MAX_SIZE];
       size_t curr_size = 0;

       resize(&array, &curr_size, 32);
       assert(array[31] == NULL);
   }
   ```
2. Use `malloc`, `free`, or similar *dynamic memory management* functions.

Comment: If I go with the first approach, if only 5 elements are needed, I'll have 200 more that will only occupy memory. But letting memory aside, if we have first array[5]={a, b, c, d, e} and then we would need only 2, with the first approach won't we end up with array[5]={a, b, NULL, c, d} ?

Comment: Also, by using malloc, my code won't compile, maybe I am doing it wrong. How can we allocate memory for 5 elements so that we would end up with the same result as `char *array[5];` ?